# Powershell: how to check if any instance of internet explorer is already running

Tags: powershell

I want to check if any instance of internet explorer, ie any window of it, is already opened or not so that i can decide that a new object has to be created or i have to attach to existing process of that IE window. This is the code below:

```
$ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows()| ? { $_.Name -eq "Windows Internet    Explorer" }
```

**I want to attach to windows() only when a window of IE is already opened and if no IE window is opened then the line should be like this:**

```
$ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application")
```

Comment: `get-process iexplore` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
if (
     Get-Process iexplore -ea silentlycontinue | 
     Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""}
)
```

Comment: @user2194017 Glad to help, remember to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Get-Process iexplore) { "Yes" } else { "No" }
```

I have no idea whether this works in a terminal services environment with many user (does a non-elevated `Get-Process` only look in your own session (and the system session) for processes?)

Comment: I would add a `-erroraction silentlycontinue` param to avoid exception on missing process.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, there was no IE window opened and still get-process was showing 4 instances of iexplore

Comment: @user2194017: If you've been testing launching IE via COM from a PSH instance you may have leaked COM references (these can take a long time to GC is PSH has no managed memory pressure).